# Providing a service only within a shared module

Tags: angular

I would like a have a service available for injection within a shared module, but that is not made available to other modules that import it. The shared module is not lazily loaded. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not quite sure why would you consider this. What is the use case?

Comment: I do not want multiple modules to access this service - only the service in which it resides. However, this module is imported into another. This functionality is possible e.g. with components where one could be declared but not exported. I was hoping for some way to accomplish the same behavior with a service.

Comment: Is it shared across multiple components?

Comment: Yes, it is shared across multiple components, but only within the shared module.

Comment: This is exactly the case when I would like to see the problem in black and white, perhaps some wireframes  or uml ... I can dream about impossible, I hope, but having the structure at the grid would help. You know, they say, everything has simple solution, perhaps you should scrutinise the whole concept a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that a service is only available to a specific set of components, register the service in the top-level component for that module. Then it will only be available to those components.

In the diagram below ... if you register the service in the ShellComponent, it is only accessible to the components under it. It won't be accessible to login, or any other sibling components (not shown in the diagram).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have done this in other cases when I had a top-level component available. Upvote for you! Especially with the pretty diagram.

However, I'm working with a complex app that is also partially still in Angular 1, so there is no parent component available for me to provide the service from at this time. :(